# Apply Flask logging middleware to only one view

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, werkzeug

I have the following middleware right now:

```
class LoggingMiddleware(object):
  def __init__(self, app):
    self._app = app

  def __call__(self, environ, resp):
    keys = ['HTTP_ACCEPT', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING',
            'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',  'HTTP_REFERER',
            'HTTP_USER_AGENT', 'PATH_INFO',
            'QUERY_STRING', 'REMOTE_ADDR']
    dumpable = { k:environ.get(k, None) for k in keys }
    print json.dumps(dumpable)      # Not sure how to get this to work with papertrail
    return self._app(environ, resp)
```

which I install via:

```
app.wsgi_app = LoggingMiddleware(app.wsgi_app)
```

This logs every single request handled by my application. I would like to limit this scope only to one view function,

```
@app.route('/foo/')
def foo
```

How can I do so?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the unmodified environment keys, just use a decorator for that particular route and get `environ` off of [`request.environ`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.environ):

```
def log_request(route):
    @functools.wraps(route)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        keys = ['HTTP_ACCEPT', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING',
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',  'HTTP_REFERER',
        'HTTP_USER_AGENT', 'PATH_INFO',
        'QUERY_STRING', 'REMOTE_ADDR']
        dumpable = { k:environ.get(k, None) for k in keys }

        # TODO: Log elsewhere
        print(json.dumps(dumpable))
        return route(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

Then just wrap the one route you care about in a logging decorator:

```
@app.route('/foo/')
@log_request
def foo():
    return 'hello from /foo/'
```

Alternatively, if you *must* use a middleware (or if you want to configure which routes get logged at run time, rather than build time), you can just look at `PATH_INFO` and log only if the path matches:

```
if environ.get('PATH_INFO') in ('/foo/', '/bar'):
    keys = # ... snip ...

return self._app(environ, resp)
```